# FileZilla keeps asking me for password and verification code

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla, two-factor-authentication

Yesterday I secured my VPS (Ubuntu 18.04) with two-factor authentication (Google Authenticator). I used [this](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/configure-ssh-2fa) tutorial to achieve this. When I tried to login to my VPS with SSH (I'm using PuTTY), it asked my password and verification code, so everything has worked perfectly.

Today I was trying to upload some files to my VPS (I have an FTP server on my VPS) with FileZilla and I got this error:

> Server sent an additional login prompt. You need to use the interactive login type.

I switched the `Logon Type` to `Interactive`, but then FileZilla asked my password and verification code for every file. This was not really helpful, so I switched to `Ask for password` but nothing has changed. I have to enter my password and verification code for every upload.

I've tried to set the `Transfer Mode` to `Active` (with `Timeout` set to `0`) as mentioned [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/528278/why-does-filezilla-ask-for-password-every-now-and-then), but unfortunately no luck with that either.

I've also tried to use WinSCP, and suprisingly there was no problem with this. I've entered my password and verification code once and WinSCP didn't ask me again. But I would stick with FileZilla if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this FileZilla forum topic](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=37078) the solution is to set `Maximum number of connections` to `1` in `Transfer Settings` (File > Site Manager > Transfer Settings).

Answer (score 1):

We get this error even if remote FTP server prompt to reset password, it's strange that FileZilla doesn't prompt to change password. I tried WINScp, changed password and all worked fine even in FileZilla post password reset.